# How to create a csv file from a list of tuples in python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I have list of tuples which I am trying to figure out how to create a csv file with the Keys as column headers and value as column values.

Below is sample list of tuples:

```
[('d_conversion_rate', 1), ('prev_2wk_visit_count', 0.0), ('sku_id', '100088-01'), ('prev_1wk_uniq_purch_cnt', 0.0)]
[('d_conversion_rate', 0), ('prev_2wk_visit_count', 6.0), ('sku_id', '100088-02'), ('prev_1wk_uniq_purch_cnt', 0.0)] 
[('d_conversion_rate', 5), ('prev_2wk_visit_count', 7.0), ('sku_id', '100088-03'), ('prev_1wk_uniq_purch_cnt', 0.0)]
```

The expected csv file should have:

```
converstion_rate,  sku_id, prev_1wk_uniq_purch_cnt
1,                  100088-02, 0.0
0,                  100088-03, 6.0
5,                  100088-04, 7.0
```

This is the code which I wrote:

```
import os
import sys
import csv
import string
import random


def import_data_to_csv(dict_d):
    with open('C:/Reports/SI_Reconciliation_Reporting/2015/output/2015-04-19/test_dump.csv', 'w') as outfile:
        fp = csv.DictWriter(outfile, dict_d[0].keys())
        fp.writeheader()
        fp.writerows(dict_d)



for row in sku_weekL:
                #print row.items()
                for key, value in row.items():
                    sku_weekTemp.append((key, value))
                print sku_weekTemp

            #print sku_weekL
            #print sku_weekL
            #print dir(sku_weekL)
            import_data_to_csv(sku_weekTemp)
```

But running the script I get an error that the tuple object has no attribute keys.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is generally expected here that you either show code you've written or describe research you've done to try to solve your problem. As your question is currently written, it sounds like a request for code. Have you made any attempts you can share with us?

Comment: Please don't use code snippets for [tag:python] they are designed for [tag:javascript] only.

Comment: task one: flaten your lists to have values only; task two use the CSV writer: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer

Comment: @skrrgwasme I included some code above.

Comment: The data structure ( list of tuple) is mandatory or could you change this input ?

Comment: @ArthurVaïsse I do understand that I don't expect to be spoon fed, but I am stuck on this task.

Answer (score 0):

The error tries to tell you that `dict_d[0]` is a tuple object and therefore has no method `keys()` (only dicts have that).

First you should have a list of the column names in your preferred order:

```
column_names = ['d_conversion_rate', 'sku_id', 'prev_1wk_uniq_purch_cnt']
```

Since the rows are already dicts with those keys, you shouldn't need to transform them.

When you have all your value_rows you can use this together with column_names to write it:

```
def import_data_to_csv(value_rows, column_names):
    with open('C:/Reports/SI_Reconciliation_Reporting/2015/output/2015-04-19/test_dump.csv', 'w') as outfile:
        fp = csv.DictWriter(outfile, column_names)
        fp.writeheader()
        fp.writerows(value_rows)
```

edit: I missed that you use DictWriter, so converting the dicts to lists is unnecessary

**edit2**: an example:

given `val_rows` like that

```
val_rows = [
    {'sku_id': 1, 'd_conversion_rate': 2, 'prev_1wk_uniq_purch_cnt': 3},
    {'sku_id': 4, 'd_conversion_rate': 5, 'prev_1wk_uniq_purch_cnt': 6}
]
```

you can use the function above with it like this

```
col_names = ['d_conversion_rate', 'sku_id', 'prev_1wk_uniq_purch_cnt']
import_data_to_csv(val_rows, col_names)

# or dynamically

import_data_to_csv(val_rows, val_rows[0].keys())
```

If your data is not formatted as list of dicts, you'll have to do a transformation. Taking your list of lists of tuples from the question above, we can transform it to a list of dicts like this

```
list_of_list_of_tuples = [
    [('d_conversion_rate', 1), ('prev_2wk_visit_count', 0.0), ('sku_id', '100088-01'), ('prev_1wk_uniq_purch_cnt', 0.0)],
    [('d_conversion_rate', 0), ('prev_2wk_visit_count', 6.0), ('sku_id', '100088-02'), ('prev_1wk_uniq_purch_cnt', 0.0)],
    [('d_conversion_rate', 5), ('prev_2wk_visit_count', 7.0), ('sku_id', '100088-03'), ('prev_1wk_uniq_purch_cnt', 0.0)]
]

val_rows = [{tup[0]: tup[1] for tup in row} for row in list_of_list_of_tuples]
```

Hope this makes it clear now.

**edit3:** 
What you wrote in the comments is missing some information, so I have to guess

```
for i in List:
    sku_L = list()  # I'm assuming you're appending each sku_L to another list somewhere further down
    for row in insL:  # I'm assuming insL is calculated in the outer loop or is just i
        insertD = dict()
        # here I assign all the values to the keys of the dictionary
        sku_L.append(insertD)
        pprint(sku_L)
```

You don't want a new list for every dictionary, so I'd pull out the list instantiation from the loop. The purpose of `pprint` is to use it without a loop, so you can see the whole thing.

```
sku_L = list()  # only one list now
for i in List:
    for row in i:  # insL is probably just i
        insertD = dict()
        # here I assign all the values to the keys of the dictionary
        sku_L.append(insertD)

pprint(sku_L)  # printing the whole thing should be a list of dicts
```

I'm pretty sure your data is actually only a list of records with each record having data in fixed positions. If this is the case you can simplify this a lot:

```
input_list = [  # this is a list of records
    [1, 0.0, 0.0, '100088-01'],
    [1, 0.0, 6.0, '100088-02']
]

sku_L = list()
for row in input_list:
    insertD = {
        'd_conversion_rate': row[0],
        'prev_2wk_visit_count': row[1],
        'prev_1wk_uniq_purch_cnt': row[2],
        'sku_id': row[3]
    }
    sku_L.append(insertD)

pprint(sku_L)
```

Comment: I did exactly what you  you told me by invoking the import_data_to_csv function by passing insertD.values() and insertD.keys() but I am getting TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: I added an example, hope this helps :)

Comment: honestly I do understand the direction you given me but when i print the list loop through all the values, my list of dictionaries appears as [{'sku_id': 1, 'd_conversion_rate': 2, 'prev_1wk_uniq_purch_cnt': 3}],  [{'sku_id': 4, 'd_conversion_rate': 5, 'prev_1wk_uniq_purch_cnt': 6}] each of which appear a newline when printed. so how can I make it like  [{'sku_id': 1, 'd_conversion_rate': 2, 'prev_1wk_uniq_purch_cnt': 3},
    {'sku_id': 4, 'd_conversion_rate': 5, 'prev_1wk_uniq_purch_cnt': 6}
] so that I could do exactly how you have advised me.

Comment: because when I do like you instucted with this code: import_data_to_csv(val_rows, val_rows[0].keys()) I am getting  an error defined below   here: fp.writerows(values_rows) NameError: global name 'values_rows' is not defined. It doesn't understand values_rows since it not defined any where but values_row is list of dictionaries.

Comment: So every dict ist wrapped in a list with one element (the dict itself)? just call it with `val_rows = map(lambda x: x[0], your_list)` and it will extract the dict out of the list for every element of `your_list`

Comment: I made the following changes: `val_rows = map(lambda x: x[0], sku_L)
import_data_to_csv(val_rows, sku_L[0].keys())` and executing the script, it prints the columns in the csv file without any records. In addition to that, it also gives prompts this error: val_rows = map(lambda x: x[0], sku_L)
KeyError: 0. sku_L is my list of dictionaries I am passing.

Comment: Well, if sku_L is already a list of dictionaries, you don't have to do the transformation. KeyError means x is (already) a dictionary and has no entry for 0.

I cannot help you, if you cannot tell me how your initial data is formatted. Either it's a list of dicts, a list of lists with one dict each or a list of tuples like in your question above. Use a debugger or `from pprint import pprint` and then `pprint(sku_L)`, so you can see how the data is formatted. You cannot solve problems by guessing.

Comment: This is how my data appears `[{'d_conversion_rate': 0,
  'd_gross_profit_amt': 0.0,
  'd_gross_rev_amt': 0.0,
  'd_uniq_purch_cnt': 0.0,
  'd_unit_sales_cnt': 0.0,
  'sku_id': '100088-01',
  'week_id': '2015-03-21'}]
[{'d_conversion_rate': 0,
  'd_gross_profit_amt': 0.0,
  'd_gross_rev_amt': 0.0,
  'd_uniq_purch_cnt': 0.0,
  'd_unit_sales_cnt': 0.0,
  'sku_id': '100088-01',
  'week_id': '2015-03-28'}]
[{'d_conversion_rate': 0,
  'd_gross_profit_amt': 0.0,
  'd_gross_rev_amt': 0.0,
  'd_uniq_purch_cnt': 0.0,
  'd_unit_sales_cnt': 0.0,
  'sku_id': '100088-01', 'week_id': '2015-04-04'}]`

Comment: Is there another list around it? You cannot have `sku_L = [{}][{}][{}]`. There has to be either a list or a tuple around it. So either `sku_L = [ [{}][{}][{}] ]` or `sku_L = [{}], [{}], [{}]`. Where do you get that data from?

Comment: This data is coming from a postgresql table which I use to perform some calculation then create a dictionary which I append to a list then flatten the list. So when I print the list, this is what I get `[{}] [{}] [{}]`.

Comment: I told you to use `pprint`, but it seems you used a `for` loop instead. Anyway, if the structure of your data is consistent the expression with map and lambda should produce no KeyError. If your data is inconsistent you will have to fix that first or post a sample of inconsistent data.

I wrote a short example, maybe that explains it better: https://gist.github.com/felixbr/37f8e4ef80dcc9191140

Comment: This is the follow of the python script ` for i in List:
    sku_L = list()
    for row in insL:
        insertD = dict()
        # here I assign all the values to the keys of the dictionary
        sku_L.append(insertD)
    pprint(sku_L)`

Comment: printing sku_L I get the following `[{'d_conversion_rate': 0,
  'd_gross_profit_amt': 0.0,
  'd_gross_rev_amt': 0.0,
  'd_uniq_purch_cnt': 0.0,
  'd_unit_sales_cnt': 0.0,
  'sku_id': '100088-01',
  'week_id': '2015-03-21'}]
[]
[{'d_conversion_rate': 0,
  'd_gross_profit_amt': 0.0, 'd_gross_rev_amt': 0.0,
  'd_uniq_purch_cnt': 0.0,
  'd_unit_sales_cnt': 0.0,
 'sku_id': '100088-01','week_id': '2015-03-28'}][][{'d_conversion_rate': 0,  'd_gross_profit_amt': 0.0, 'd_gross_rev_amt': 0.0, 'd_uniq_purch_cnt': 0.0,
'd_unit_sales_cnt': 0.0, 'sku_id': '100088-01', 'week_id': '2015-04-04'}]`

Comment: I still have to guess where `List` and `insL` come from, but I made another edit to my answer.

Comment: using the last post, this is how the data is formatted `[{'d_conversion_rate': 0,'d_gross_profit_amt': 0.0,'d_gross_rev_amt': 0.0,'d_uniq_purch_cnt': 0.0, 'd_unit_sales_cnt': 0.0,'sku_id': '100088-01','week_id': '2015-03-21'}, {'d_conversion_rate': 0,'d_gross_profit_amt': 0.0,
'd_gross_rev_amt': 0.0, 'd_uniq_purch_cnt': 0.0,'d_unit_sales_cnt': 0.0, 'sku_id': '100088-01', 'week_id': '2015-03-28'},{'d_conversion_rate': 0,'d_gross_profit_amt': 0.0,'d_gross_rev_amt': 0.0,'d_uniq_purch_cnt': 0.0,'d_unit_sales_cnt': 0.0,'sku_id': '100088-01','week_id': '2015-04-04'}]`

Comment: I am now able to produce the output file. Is there a way to remove spaces from the csv file, this is my output: `d_conversion_rate,sku_id,week_id,d_gross_rev_amt,d_unit_sales_cnt,d_uniq_purch_cnt,d_gross_profit_amt

0,100088-01,2015-03-21,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0

0,100088-01,2015-03-28,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0

0,100088-01,2015-04-04,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0` there are spaces between the column keys and the data rows.

Comment: To remove the empty rows,  I got it solved by using the `wb` mode.

Comment: If you don't like the formatting, you have to choose a different dialect and pass it as parameter to the DictWriter.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution based on what I understood about your problem.
If any question fell free to ask. I personally dislike the python standard library `csv` and always do without it when needing to write csv file.

```
def asDic(listOfTuple):
    """ Convert a list of tuple [(key,value)] into a dictionary """
    return {i:j for (i,j) in listOfTuple}

def exportLine(lineMembers, outputFile, separator):
    """
    exportLine(["lineMembers"foo", "bar", "foo"], file, "separator",")
        -> file.write("foo, bar, foo\n")
    """
    lineString = ""
    for i in range(len(lineMembers)-1):
        lineString += str(lineMembers[i]) + separator
    #Append the last element without a separator, instead add a end of line
    lineString += str(lineMembers[-1]) + "\n"
    outputFile.write(lineString)

def exportCSV(data, headers, outputFile, separator = ", "):
    """
    Exports the data into the outputFile using the given headers.
    It is possible to generate any separated value file by overriding the default separator.

    data : a list of dict object. Their content will be accesed using the values of headers as keys.
    """
    #export the headers
    exportLine(headers, outputFile, separator)

    for dataset in data : 
        #Build the data line
        exportData = [ dataset[header] for header in headers ]
        #and export it
        exportLine(exportData, outputFile, separator)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    row1 = [('d_conversion_rate', 1), ('prev_2wk_visit_count', 0.0), ('sku_id', '100088-01'), ('prev_1wk_uniq_purch_cnt', 0.0)]
    row2 = [('d_conversion_rate', 0), ('prev_2wk_visit_count', 6.0), ('sku_id', '100088-02'), ('prev_1wk_uniq_purch_cnt', 0.0)]
    row3 = [('d_conversion_rate', 5), ('prev_2wk_visit_count', 7.0), ('sku_id', '100088-03'), ('prev_1wk_uniq_purch_cnt', 0.0)]

    data = [row1, row2, row3]

    #get the list of headers that will be exported
    columnHeader = [i for (i,j) in data[0]]
    #transform the data to allow access them by field
    data = [asDic(row) for row in data]

    #you may add here whatever code you want in order to sort/filter/remove some headers here.
    #Removing one header will remove the column from the final export.
    columnHeader.pop(1)#commenting this will add the column prev_2wk_visit_count to the file.

    outputFile = open("./output.csv", 'w')
    exportCSV(data, columnHeader, outputFile)
    outputFile.close()
```